# RecyclerView inside of NestedScrollView not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have Layout contains `ImageSliderView` and `RecyclerView`, I want to make `ImageSliderView` scroll  with `RecyclerView`, for that, I disabled the `RecyclerView` scroll by adding this code :

```
recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.rc);
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

And I added `androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView` as a parent as below :

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#008080"
    android:fillViewport="false">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#008080"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:context=".Fragments.Recent">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_page"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/imageborder"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <com.glide.slider.library.SliderLayout
                android:id="@+id/imgtoday"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="180dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relative_page">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:numColumns="2"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

The app freezes at run time, can anyone help me to get resolve my issue

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I ended up adding `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` inside the `NestedScrollView`

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:background="#008080"
    android:fillViewport="false">
```

There are people that instead of adding it to `NestedScrollView` they add inside the `RecyclerView` and it works too.

It did the trick for me, also what you can do is change the `height` to `wrap_content`

Comment: thank you for your answer, but unfortunately, my app still freezes at runtime

Comment: Have you solved this? In order to help other people if this helped you feel free to upvote and mark this as a correct answer. Thanks :)